# Display GridView Selected Row data in TextBox outside GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below code is not showing any error , still doesn't provide output.

**Asp.code**

```
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" onclick="CheckAll(this)"/>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="updatedby" HeaderText="updatedby" SortExpression="updatedby" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="password" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mail" HeaderText="mail" SortExpression="mail" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="imagename" HeaderText="imagename" SortExpression="imagename" />
               <%--<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="image" EditImageUrl="~/images/delete.jpg" HeaderText="Delete" />--%>

            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="uploadimage" HeaderText="uploadimage" ControlStyle-Width = "60" ControlStyle-Height = "100">

            </asp:ImageField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" >
                    <ItemTemplate>                  
               <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.jpg"
                   OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />                              
                    </ItemTemplate>   
               </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text="Choose" CssClass="linkbutton"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Get details" BackColor="#33CCFF" CssClass="getdetails"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />

</asp:GridView>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName=="Choose")
        {
            GridViewRow row = ((e.CommandSource as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
            TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            TextBox3.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
            TextBox4.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code.problem is in `CommandName`, because you have not provided CommandName in your LinkButton

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text="Choose" CssClass="linkbutton" CommandName="Choose"></asp:LinkButton>
          </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i changed bt same probelm came